# Disadvantages to hosting Windows Forms Control in WPF Application?

Tags: wpf, winforms

Are there any disadvantages to hosting a Windows Forms Control in a WPF Application?

My first thought is that performance might be hurt a little bit.  Also, there is the air gap issue between the forms control and the wpf application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Jeff wrote plus there are also some graphical glitches as well (especially when resizing).

Comment: I would have liked a little bit more proof besides conjecturer, but that might be tough to come by.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of proof do you have on your mind. I had tried to host a WinForms components and later dumped it because the glitches were not worth the component (specifically, it was ScintillaNET, I replaced it with native WPF AvalonEdit, whcih is btw much better editor than ScintillaNET). I guess you can do a quick test to see yourself (just host a simple WinForms control in a simple WPF and try resizing it and dragging it around).

Comment: More or less an article.  Basically, something I can point back to.  There's only so much you can do with a test that I create.

Answer (score 3):

My experience:

1. Slight performance impact. Generally resolvable by using double buffering though...
2. Some Winforms events are not fired correctly or reliably. This is a known issue and has workarounds although I've found it pretty annoying.

In general though, I've hosted entire Winforms applications in a WPF Browser Application with success.